Google Workspace MigrateのAPIクォータ制限と緩和申請について
Google Workspace Migrate（GWM）を使用してExchange Onlineからメールを移行しようとしています。
メール移行の際にはおそらく内部的にはGMail APIを叩いていると思うのですが、
下記のページの記載がわかりにくくサポートに問い合わせても有効な回答がつかないため質問させてください。
https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/quota?hl=ja
①「ユーザー 1 人あたり 1 秒あたり 250 の割り当てユニット」の「ユーザー」は移行を実施するGWMのユーザー、移行対象となるGWSのユーザーのどちらを指しますか？
②「ユーザーあたりのレート制限」は緩和申請が可能なものでしょうか？
③緩和申請が可能だとして、実際に緩和されるまでにどの程度リードタイムが必要でしょうか？（2〜3営業日程度、など）
